# How can I do full text search in Mongoose with multiple parameters, but with an AND link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have the problem that I can do the full text search with one word smoothly, but how can I search for several parameters or rather enter them?

my function:

```
    export const searching = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      Company.find({ $or: [{ $text: { $search: req.query.search as string } }] }).exec((err, docs) => {
        console.log(req.query.search?.toString()!)
        if (docs) {
          res.status(200).json(docs)
        } else {
          console.log(err)
        }
      })
}
```

I want to combine two parameters with AND and thus search for the data containing exactly these two parameters and nothing else.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) function to do this.

```
Company.aggregate([
  {
    $match : {$fieldName : 1st phrase here}
  },
  {
    $match : {$fieldName : 2nd phrase here} 
  }
])
```

Code explanation :
In the first stage, mongodb will find all documents with the first phrase that you have entered. This is basically what your current query does. Now, the output of this stage will be the input of next stage where we match the 2nd phrase.
Hence, we are filtering the documents in a step-wise process. First filter the documents having the 1st phrase then find out the documents having the 2nd phrase from the previous result.